# How can we call a server side script? whether in a document class or sub-class?

Tags: actionscript-3

while working with a server side script (php or aspx) which returns some data(from the database)  can we call it in a sub-class or do we have to make the calls in the document class itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it in either place, but I prefer it being in a sub class that specifically handles interation with web services, to better organize my code. URLRequest + URLLoader are the classes I use for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method below to load a php file in the same directory as the SWF files on your server:

```
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.php");
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    loader.load(request);

    function completeHandler(evt:Event) {

    instancename1.text = evt.target.data.symbol_1;// or trace()
    instancename2.text = evt.target.data.symbol_2;
```

Below is a simple php Test script:

```
<?php

$returnVars['symbol_1'] = "item1";
$returnVars['symbol_2'] = "item2";
$returnString = http_build_query($returnVars);
echo $returnString;

?>
```

Comment: i know the method to communicate with the server-side script. What i want to know is the location where we can implement the loader method(the above one). Do we have to write the loader methods in the document class itself or can i write it in a sub-class? anyways thanks for the help...

Comment: I dont think it would matter, simple solution would be a trial and error, cant hurt plus its educational, let us know what your conclusion is.